# Angular BehaviorSubject events emited multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a weird behavior with RxJS observable and I cannot figure it why.

I have a service which exposes a `BehaviorSubject` and emits events :

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {
    private searchSubject: BehaviorSubject<SearchQueryParams>;

    updateSearch(search: any) {
        this.searchSubject.next(search);
    }

    onSearchUpdate(): Observable<any> {
        return this.searchSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In my component, I subscribe to this `Observable` with a `shareReplay()` because I'm using multiple `async` pipe in template :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rp-produit-recherche',
    template: '<div class="search">
    <app-facets class="facets" [facets]="searchResult$ | async"></app-facets>
    <app-results [results]="searchResult$ | async"></app-results>
</div>
',
    styleUrls: ['./produit-recherche.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

   public searchResult$: Observable<any>;

   ...

   ngOnInit() {
        this.searchResult$ = this.SearchService.onSearchUpdate().pipe(
            switchMap((searchRequest) => {
                return this.apiService.search(searchRequest);
            }),
            shareReplay()
        );
    }

}
```

This actually works fine. When an event is emitted, api is called and results is what I want.

Now I'have added a second `Route` serving the same component. And my issue has started.

When I navigate from route `a` to route `b`. Event is still emitted but in subscription it's received twice. If I navigate again between those routes I got an n events + 1, etc.

*My routes :*

```
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                resolve: {
                    searchQueryParams: SearchQueryParamsResolverGuard
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'a',
                        component: SearchComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'b',
                        component: SearchComponent
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

And resolver which emits event :

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchQueryParamsResolverGuard implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): SearchQueryParams {
        const search = route.queryParamMap.get('search');
        return this.searchService.updateSearch(search);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this happening. Component is destroy when navigate so subscription should have ended.

I hope someone have already meet this issue and find a way to solve it. Thanks

Comment: When is `this.SearchService.updateSearch()` called?

Comment: at several place but in this scenario in `SearchQueryParamsResolverGuard` resolver

Comment: I may have found the source of the problem : `shareReplay()` If I remove it, problem is solve but in template `Observable` is subscribe at multiple place. But I need to call api only once and share data. `share()` seems to be more adapted. I need to understand difference.

Comment: Please try with `shareReplay(1)` @MartinChoraine

Comment: Already try but same result as `shareReplay()`

Comment: Any reason for using shareReplay(), without it's running fine.

Comment: No it's not working fine because my observable is subscribe twice (two `async` in template) so when event is emitted from service, api is called twice but I would like to have only call.

Comment: @MartinChoraine, please check updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the issue is because of `shareReplay`, ( **[in detail](https://blog.strongbrew.io/share-replay-issue/)** )

**Reason :** The shareReplay operator does not clean up streams when they have not yet completed.This will introduce a memory leak into our application.

```
shareReplay({
    bufferSize: 1,
    refCount: true
})
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-share-replay-issue)** ( **Issue** + **Solution** ) Check `product.component.ts`

---

**This might be the case for others:**

All you need is to `unsubscribe` this on `ngOnDestroy`,

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.searchResult$.unsubscribe();
}
```

> **Reason :**
>
> What happens here is its **subscribing same observable multiple time** and
>   it **never gets destroyed**, so if you route through your site and come back
>   to the same page **again and again it will subscribe** one more time **( I got an n events + 1)**, so when the emit event
>   happen once but there are multiple listeners now.

Comment: I cannot unsubcribe because I'm using `async` pipe so Angular handle to subscribe and unsubscribe for me.

Comment: @MartinChoraine, if that's the case then this should not be happen, just try it out and check if its working or not

Comment: Behavior is the same

Comment: @MartinChoraine, will you please share the code for SearchQueryParamsResolverGuard?

Comment: Thanks you so much ! I just figure it out so I added same answer. What this issue learn me is that I need to read more about `multicasting` operators

Comment: @MartinChoraine, Great, I also learned new thing, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have understand what's going on :

I need to learn more about `multicast`/`share`/`publish` operators.

The problem come from my `shareReplay()` usage. I need to share only the last event. So I have to add configuration :

```
shareReplay({
    bufferSize: 1,
    refCount: true
})
```

**bufferSize : 1** will emits only last event
**refCount: true** will automates the process of connecting and disconnecting an observable connectable

For my usage I can use `share()` instead of `shareReplay()`.

> For further information (*I'm not 100% confident so do not hesitate to correct me.*)

`shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true))` == `share()`
`shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: false))` == `shareReplay(1)`
`shareReplay({refCount: false))` == `shareReplay()`